# How to update controller and action name in url using Ajax/JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am developing a project having two controllers named as "Student" and "Profile".

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Login(){}
    public ActionResult Home(){}

} 

public class ProfileController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Details(){}
}
```

When I am at my Home page after login, it gives me the following url

```
url:http://localhost:3451/Student/Home?username=student%40gmail.com
```

and when I click on Ajax based Profile link give below

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "Details", "Profile", 
                new { username = Session["username"].ToString() }, 
                new AjaxOptions() 
                { 
                 UpdateTargetId = "ajax",
                 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
                 HttpMethod = "POST", 
                 OnSuccess = "changeUrl(data)" }, 
                 new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-user", 
                 title = "Profile", style = "color:white;" 
                })
```

gives me the Student Profile but url remains same but I want the url to be changed something like that

```
url:http://localhost:3451/Profile/Details/
```

Comment: So why not just post to that controller why use Ajax?

Comment: just to save server headache, so that server should not send the common hmtl/css again and again

Comment: If it really is that much html/css being loaded then you could look into using the javascript location.hash to change url.

Comment: it is possible to change action name in the url but i wanna know that is it possible to change the controller name too ???

Comment: I think this is what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page